# How to setSelectionPaths() for a JIDE CheckBoxTree using the CheckBoxTreeSelectionModel?

Tags: java, checkbox, tree, jide

I'm using the CheckBoxTree class which is part of the JIDE Common Layer package (http://jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm). What I'd like to be able to do is save and load the state of the CheckBoxTreeSelectionModel which is what tracks what boxes are checked or not. I can save it by just saving selectionModel.getSelectionPaths(), but my problem is with loading it. When I selectionModel.setSelectionPaths() it only checks the boxes for the root and the leaf of the path, but nothing in between. Strangely enough, this also happens when I save the results of getSelectionPaths() then feed it directly into setSelectionPaths().

For the FileSystemModel, I'm using some code I found which likes to use File objects instead of TreeNodes. I have tried different combinations of FileSystemModels and CheckBoxTrees that I've found in various places on the Net, and the results are always the same. I've probably put close to 20 hours in on this issue... which is a bit embarrassing to admit. Any help is appreciated!

My code is as follows. This creates the CheckBoxTree and attempts to load it with "/Documents and Settings/Administrator" which results in "/" and "Administrator" and all it's children being checked, but not "Documents and Settings".

```
public class CheckBoxTreeFrame {
    private FileSystemModel fileSystemModel = null;
    private CheckBoxTree checkBoxTree = null;
    private JFrame main_frame = null;
    private CheckBoxTreeSelectionModel selectionModel = null;

    public CheckBoxTreeFrame(){
        // create the model
        fileSystemModel = new FileSystemModel(new File(File.separator));
        // use the model for the Tree
        checkBoxTree = new CheckBoxTree(fileSystemModel);
        checkBoxTree.setEditable(false);
        // model for the checkboxes (not the directory structure)
        selectionModel = checkBoxTree.getCheckBoxTreeSelectionModel();
        // event listener
        checkBoxTree.getCheckBoxTreeSelectionModel().addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(selectionModel.getSelectionPath());
            }
        });

        // setup a little UI window for the tree.
        main_frame = new JFrame("Frame Title");
        main_frame.add(checkBoxTree);
        main_frame.setSize(400, 400);
        main_frame.setVisible(true);

        // run the loading test
        runTest();
    }

    public void runTest(){
        File[] finalPath = new File[3];
        finalPath[0] = (File)selectionModel.getModel().getRoot();
        finalPath[1] = new File(finalPath[0],"Documents and Settings");
        finalPath[2] = new File(finalPath[1],"Administrator");

        selectionModel.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(finalPath));
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I found a few hints, but I'm not sure how to apply it. http://www.jidesoft.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=10858&p=52866&hilit=checkboxtree#p52866

Answer (score 2):

The CheckBoxTreeSelectionModel is basically a DefaultTreeSelectionModel (as in Swing). The trick the tree path has to exist in the TreeModel. I don't think the way you create a TreePath in runTest will create the same tree path. It'd better to get the tree path from the tree. Try this, it will work.

```
checkBoxTree.getCheckBoxTreeSelectionModel().addSelectionPath(checkBoxTree.getPathForRow(2));
```